# Angular2 Unit Testing Setup issue

Tags: unit-testing, angular

[Testing Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html) 
I have been following it.

NOTE : I have my app running without testing part.

Problem: I'm unable to load **unit-tests.html**. I think problem is very small but unable to figure it out. I'm using **VisualCode** and when I hit **F5** it runs my app only. So how to load **unit-tests.html**?

My setup is as follow.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",


  "scripts": {

    "test": "live-server --open=unit-tests.html",  
     //<------ I have added this as mentioned.

    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
     //<------ I tried to disable this line as well.

    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
    },


  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

**unit-tests.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <title>Ng App Unit Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">


  <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

  <script>
    System.config({
      packages: {
        'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
      }
    });

    System.import('app/app.spec')
      .then(window.onload)
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.spec.ts**  (NOTE: within **app folder**, **app.spec.ts** is there)

```
it('true is true', () => expect(true).toEqual(true));
```

Comment: you could just open a browser, navigate to `localhost:PORTNUMBER/unit-tests.html` replace PORTNUMBER with the port live-server starts on. Or open npm, navigate to your project folder using `cd` then type `npm run test`

Comment: Yes. But I'd like `system.js` to load  `testing file`.

Comment: This way it also says that unable to get `app/app.spec`

Comment: take a look here: https://github.com/Coly010/angular2-test-setup and look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

My unit-tests.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <title>Angular2 Unit Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
  <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>

  <script src="../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- #1. add the system.js library -->
  <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

  <!--<script src="systemjs.builder.js"></script>-->

  <script>

     var fileList = ['sanity.spec'];

     System.baseURL = 'bin/tests/';

     multiImport(fileList)
     .then(window.onload)
     .catch(console.error.bind(console));


     function multiImport(modules) {
        return Promise.all(modules.map(function(m) { return System.import(m) }))
     }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this makes it easy to tell system js to load multiple files